# Can a ActionResult open a specific folder on a server?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

For example, I need only documents from a folder on the server drive `X:\Docs` for an online web application. Is there a way that a button on the website will open `X:\Docs` by default? I have tried this to open specific folders with no luck:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpFileCollection file)
{
    var path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName("X:\Docs");
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I am new to C# and MVC. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable directory browsing of that folder and then having the button (or href) to point to the url. You don't event need a controller method for it.

Updated: if the folder is not under your website's root you will need to do some work by yourself. For example

```
@foreach (string path in Directory.GetFiles("X:\Docs"))
{
    <div>
       <!--doc link-->
    </div>
}
```

You will need to have read permission for that drive ofc

As Luke pointed out you could alo do this inside your controller and pass it into your View which I also think it might be a better approach since View should be responsible for reading and rendering data

Comment: One suggestion that I would make is that you should perform the logic to get your file path list within the controller and not within the view like this.  The list should then be passed in the model to your view.